# Does a pom.xml.template tell me everything I need to know to use the project as a dependency

Tags: lucene, maven-2, lucene-highlighter

I'm trying to add the lucene sandbox contribution called [term-highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/lucene-sandbox/index.html#Term%20Highlighter) to my pom.xml.
I'm not really that familiar with Maven, but the code has a [pom.xml.template](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/java/trunk/contrib/highlighter/pom.xml.template) which 
seems to imply if I add a dependency that looks like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It might work. Can someone help me out in adding a lucene-community project to my pom.xml file?

Thanks for the comments, it turns out that adding the version was all I needed, and I just guessed it should match the lucene-core version I was using.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the version number, but you only have to do it once in a project structure. That is, if the version number is defined in a parent pom, you don't have to give the version number again. (But you don't even have to provide the dependency in this case since the dependency will be inherited anyways.)

Answer (score 1):

You have it right, but you probably want to add the version as well:

[From The Maven 5 minute tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```